# Match data from two tables in sql

Tags: sql

How would I match 2 rows data that share a common column from 2 separate tables in SQL?

Example:

Table 1:

```
Name, Height_year_1, Weight_year_1
John, 60, 120
Joe, 70, 145
```

Table 2:

```
Name, Height_year_2, Weight_year_2
John, 62, 125
Joe, 70, 150
```

And I want to find the average of John's year 1 and year 2 height and weights (same with Joe)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  Table1.Name, 
  avg(Height_year_1 + Height_year_2) AS Average_height, 
  avg(Weight_year_1 + Weight_year_2) AS Average_weight
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Name = Table2.Name
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a3b6/15)

Answer (score 0):

you can execute a command like this:

```
"Select avg(x.Height_year_1,x.Weight_year_1) 
 From (Select * from table1 t1, table2 t2 where
 t1.Name = t2.Name and
 Height_year_1 = Height_year_2 and 
 Weight_year_1 = Weight_year_2") x
```